# how do you create persistCookie in WebMatrix

Tags: cookies, webmatrix, persist

I am trying to get the remember me function to work in starter site in WebMatrix. From what I can see I need to set up a persistCookie put I cannot find code for WebMatrix. If anyone knows how to set this up or another way to get the remember me checkbox to work that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the cookie is persisted for 30 minutes. If you want to persist it for longer periods, you need to add a section to the `system.web` node of your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="10080"/> <!--one week-->
</authentication>
```

The `timeout` value is measured in minutes, so the example above will persist the cookie for 7 days.

Shared hosting providers often recycle the application pool every 20 minutes or so. If the keys for validation and encryption are configured in the machine.config to auto-generate (the default), any existing cookies will no longer work as the encryption will have changed. That will result in the user having to log in again. To prevent this happening, you can generate your own keys in your web.config file thereby opting out of auto-generation at runtime.

There are online tools that generate keys, but you can also use IIS to generate keys for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager.aspx

Comment: It works locally but not on the server. It still times out about 20-30 minutes.

Comment: That suggests to me that you have not uploaded a revised version of the web.config.

Comment: I deleted and reloaded the web.config file from the server and it still times me out. I have GoDaddy shared hosting and they say that the session length is set to 20 minutes and I cannot change that but I should be able to change the cookie to work.

Comment: Forms timeout has nothing to do with sessions. What value did you set the timeout to?

Comment: I kept it at 10080 as you had for testing

Comment: Have you confirmed that a cookie is being created? Does it feature the correct expiry date?

Comment: I have .ASPAUTH that shows a 1 month exp and a _RequestVerificationToken_L09NUw2 that shows it expires at the end of the browsing session

Comment: Delete the ASPAUTH token. Then try logging in again.

Comment: I deleted the cookies from my browser. It still shows exp of 1 month both if I click remember me or not, but it still times out after 20-30 minutes

Comment: It seems to me that the files on your server do not match the local ones.

Comment: I deleted all files from the server and reloaded them. It now shows the proper time of expiration for .ASPAUTH but still times out in 20 mnutes

Comment: Your session might time out, but the cookie means you are still authenticated. As I said previously, sessions and forms timeout are not the same thing.

Comment: what I mean is it does not keep me logged in even though the cookie is still showing

Comment: do you think it could be a setting that GoDaddy has that is preventing it from working?

Comment: Quite possibly. See if this helps: http://pablissimo.com/351/remember-me-checkbox-not-working-with-forms-authentication-on-shared-hosting. If it does, I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: the generated code from http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey worked great. Thanks again for your help Mike